# Importing .txt file as a table in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms, txt

I'm trying to upload a text file (.txt) which has over 2 million rows into SQL Server via the Import and Export Wizard.

However I am getting this error, despite the preview looking fine:

> Executing (Error)
>
> Messages
>
> Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "NAME" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".
>
> Error 0xc020902a: Data Flow Task 1: The "Source - ADDRESS_POINT_txt.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[NAME]" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "Source - ADDRESS_POINT_txt.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[NAME]" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.

Comment: Please check your table column length with max length value in the file. you can check column of "NAME"

Comment: It is saying name field was shorter than what was in text file or encountered a character that is incompatible with table's codepage. This is more a suggestion than a solution, you can use some other backend that is easy for text file importing (like VFP, PostgreSQL, SQLite, excel ...) and then use some C# code with SqlBulkCopy for the real import.  It is presumably would take 2-3 minutes to import then.

Comment: If you're using the current 2019 SQL Server version you could use *polybase*

Comment: How many characters is NAME? Make that archar(n) or varchar(max)!

Comment: @ASH I can't find where to edit it before running the import/export wizard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this right now and it looks like this on my system.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! It finally succeeded!